# Is there a way to rename the filenames of Gatsby-generated JavaScript?

Tags: gatsby

In particular I'm interested in filtering specific words that occur as part of component names in some of the generated JavaScript files.

Is there a way to do this with Gatsby?

Comment: I misread the question and thought you wanted to change path names, not filenames from build.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not something Gatsby currently can do — why do you want to do that?